# лаечный / лаячный

Tags: прилагательные

Как правильно образовать притяжательное прилагательное от слова "лайка" в предложении:

*Щенок имел хорошие ла(я,е)чьи качества.*

"Грамота.Ру", ссылаясь на словарь Ожегова, Шведовой, утверждает вариант - лаечный. Неужели он единственный?..
https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=spravka